# データに格納されているクラスごとに処理を分けたい

Tags: python

データに格納されているクラスごとに処理を分けたいです。今

```
class Test():
    def test(self, user_code):
        (question, answer_code, type) = ans()
        if user_code == ans_code:
           return True
        else:
           return False

class Array(Test):
    def ans(self):

        question = "TEST1"
        answer_code ="TEST1"

        return (question,answer_code,"Array")

class For(Test):
    def ans(self):

        question = "TEST2"
        ans_code ="TEST2"

        return (question,ans_code,"For")
```

のようにコードを書きました。user_dataのデータベースに
question_id | user_id | ans | type
1              1        TEST1  Array
2              2        TEST3  For     という風にデータが格納されています。
このuser_dataのデータベースのtypeにArrayが入っているときは、class Arrayのansメソッドを呼び出し、Forが入っているときはclass Forのansメソッドを呼び出したいです。user_code引数にuser_dataのデータベースのansの中身が入っています。
そのようにデータベースの内容と呼び出したいクラスを紐づけるには上記のコードにどう追加すれば良いでしょうか？
コードを実行すると、ans()メソッドが定義されていないと出ます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コードと説明を読んでもこれをどのように使うのか、何をやりたいのかはいまいちわかりませんので、とりあえずPythonの文法レベルでの回答となります。

ans() が見つからないのはそのような関数を定義していないからです。ans()メソッドを呼び出したいのでしたら、

```
(question, answer_code, type) = ans()
```

を以下のように修正してください。

```
(question, answer_code, type) = self.ans()
```

ついでに次の行で参照している ans_code という変数も未定義です。

```
if user_code == ans_code:
```

self.ans()の戻り値と比較したいのではないかとと想像されるので、もしそうであれば以下のように修正してください。

```
if user_code == answer_code:
```

以上、ご確認ください。